# php-fpm: why do I have a process memory usage higher than memory_limit

Tags: php, performance, memory, php-fpm

I know that there are a lot of related subjects, but I did not found my answer.

I have a dedicated server with 32Go of RAM (but I want php-fpm to use only 12Go max), and I have a php-fpm (7.2.13) running along side an apache server.

My problem is that each php-fpm process is consuming too much memory...
I mesured it with

```
ps -ylC php-fpm --sort:rss
```

And the output was 269 process, each of them with 121Mo in the RSS column, and a total RAM usage on the dedicated server of 3Go.

I also made some php profiling with "memory_get_peak_usage()" php function, and each of my script use an average of 6Mo (peak usage !) and a maximum peak usage of 50Mo (but it is a very specific case).
After this profiling, I tried to set the "memory_limit" to 10Mo, the specific case was not working, so I set it to 50Mo and all was ok (normal behaviour).

My two questions are:

- As my php scripts does not exceed a peak usage of 50Mo, and as I set a memory_limit of 50Mo, why EACH of my php-fpm process are 121Mo big ?
- How is it possible to have 269 processes running with each of them 121Mo big ? The total amout of memory would be 269*121 = 32Go (and when I made this profiling, the total amount of RAM used is the dedicated server was only 3Go ...)

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Much of the memory used by the php-fpm processes is shared between all of them. Only a fraction is unique to each process.  You can see how much is shared vs unique using the `smem` utility. First install it with

```
sudo apt-get install smem
```

or

```
sudo yum install smem
```

Then run `smem -P php-fpm`.

You'll get a list of your php-fpm processes with the following info:

**Swap**: Memory swapped to disk

**USS**: Unique resident memory (RAM) used by this process

**PSS**: Total resident memory used by this process, including a proportional amount of the shared memory. Sum this column to get the total actual memory used by the processes without double-counting shared memory.

**RSS**: The resident memory used by this process, including ALL of the shared memory, as reported in `ps`.  As you noted, summing this will inflate the total, as it repeatedly counts the shared memory.

Answer (score 0):

First question: the `php-fpm` processes need memory for the php interpreter itself; the 50Mb limit limits the amount of RAM the script can consume, in addition to what the interpreter needs no matter what.

Second question: your processes probably shared quite a bit of memory (definitely all code pages that were loaded from the same binary/library).

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
Is there a way to see the memory really used by a process, without the shared memory ? In order to be able to tune my php-fpm max-children correctly

Comment: And I don't have Opcache enabled on my server, so I don't understand what can be this shared memory, if this is not my code/lib opcode in cache

Comment: The shared memory is also "really used by the process" -- it's just used by more than one process. Memory management in a modern operating system is very complex. Instead of trying to work out how much RAM each process needs individually, I suggest either using cgroups to limit the total amount of RAM all `php-fpm` processes together can consume, or at least using cgroups to track their total usage and adjust their number based on that.

Comment: My php-fpm is in a docker, so I just have to set the "mem_limit" of this docker to 12Go and it will be fine (and disable swap). But I wanted to know exactly how many processes I could fit in these 12Go. I mean, if in the 121Mo , 75Mo are "shared memory" used by all processes, I can consider that each process use 46Mo, and find out the right "max_children" for 12Go.. but I don't know how to find this number. I tried to look at cgroups but I'm not sure to understand how I must do it ?

Comment: This morning on my docker, I had 2 active processes, and 38 idle (so 40 total processes). The memory taken by my docker was 668Mo. If I take 500Mo / 40 processes, it gives ~13Mo by process. Does that sound correct to you ?

Comment: It's certainly in the right ballpark. But I'm certain there are going to be outliers (processes with higher or lower memory requirements).